# Using jbuilder variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have my jbuilder variables posting a response on a form update (ex: update.html.erb update.js.builder) and I was just wondering how I go about using these variables in my jquery functions to update texts fields within a view after an update. Just to clarify I am using ruby on rails 4.

Example I have an update action that's handled by a remote ajax call.

update.js.builder:

```
json.extract! @person, :name, :gender
```

My response from builder after form update is:

```
{"name":"Mark","gender":"Male"}
```

I just want to access these variables in my jquery syntax so that I can change certain html id's text using these new instances. My question is how do I use/access these json variables in my jquery file? Do I need to convert them to javascript variables or do I have access to them and if so, how?